# java lang RuntimeException:

Tags: java, android

so basically, i'm new to java and android studio. I know the basics but I'm not that good yet.

I get this error when I try to run an the app on my phone. Going through other threads didn't help me either as I basically have just one background image in the MainActivity. I have to add one more but when I do it and try to run the app, it crashes.

size of background image: 115kb
size of the image I still have to add: 164 KB (tried to compress it to 74Kb, didn't work.)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(430377192bytes) bitmap.
```

I saw this in another thread which was supposed to be put in the manifest which hasn't helped either:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

I hope I have provided enough information needed to answer the question, if you need more please tell me.

Again: I am new to this.

Comment: Could you please show the code for this? The bitmap consumes 430377192 / 1024 / 1024 = 410 MB memory.

Comment: [look the official doc please](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: @oschlueter. No, it's (approximating a square image) `sqrt(430377192 / 4)` which gives an extimated image size of `10372 * 10372`. I still must see a device with such a resolution. If you ask WHY `/ 4`, it's because R, G, B and A (a bitmap's color components) are 4 bytes.

Comment: @Rotwang the exception complains about the image being a 430377192 bytes bitmap. It doesn't matter if the image is square, not square or flipped upside down, 430377192 bytes is somewhat above 410 MB in size...

Comment: @oschlueter Yes. But I just pointed out the right way to approximate that. As Commonsware also spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

430377192 bytes is the equivalent of a 10372 x 10372 pixel image. This is **much too large**. Moreover, it is far larger than any Android device screen that you are ever likely to encounter.

So, find this drawable resource, and reduce its resolution to something more reasonable.

If you placed this drawable resource in `res/drawable/`, please understand that `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, representing images designed for `-mdpi` screens (~160 dpi). Those images will be upsampled to higher resolutions on higher-density screens (e.g., double along each axis for `-xhdpi` screens). Either prepare dedicated drawables for appropriate densities, or move this image into `res/drawable-nodpi/`.

Comment: nice explanation.